# Extracting only dates from a text file and ignoring large numbers

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have a text file and I want to extract all dates from it but somehow my code is also extracting the other values like

> Procedure #:  10075453.

Below is a small sample of that file:

```
Patient Name:  Mills, John      Procedure #:  10075453
October 7, 2017
Med Rec #:  747901                  Visit ID:  110408731
Patient Location:  OUTPATIENT               Patient Type:  OUTPATIENT
DOB:07/09/1943      Gender:  F  Age: 73Y    Phone:  (321)8344-0456
```

Can I get an idea how I could approach this problem?

```
doc = []
with open('Clean.txt', encoding="utf8") as file:
   for line in file:
      doc.append(line)

df = pd.Series(doc)

def date_extract():

    one = df.str.extract(r'((?:\d{,2}\s)?(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]*(?:-|\.|\s|,)\s?\d{,2}[a-z]*(?:-|,|\s)?\s?\d{2,4})')

    two = df.str.extract(r'((?:\d{1,2})(?:(?:\/|-)\d{1,2})(?:(?:\/|-)\d{2,4}))')

    three = df.str.extract(r'((?:\d{1,2}(?:-|\/))?\d{4})')

    dates = pd.to_datetime(one.fillna(two).fillna(three).replace('Decemeber','December',regex=True).replace('Janaury','January',regex=True))
    return pd.Series(dates.sort_values())
```

Comment: @rock321987:
Thanks, Saurabh! I am little new to StackOverflow

Comment: Why not remove those numbers after you get them with dates?

Comment: Hi Bharath! Yes it is your previous code. Well, it is not extracting those values but it is giving an error for those values
Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1007-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: the answer was particular to a problem, I dont think it will suit every date extracting problem out there. You need to modify things a bit.